# Do I have any legal right to fair grading by my university? (UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, grading

I have recently been given a 0 for one of my online exams at university due to technical difficulties that meant I was unable to submit the exam before the end of exam time. Unfortunately this was quite an important exam and will likely have a big effect on my grade this year.

I think that although I was partly to blame, the university is also partly at fault. So currently I'm trying to dispute the issue with them, hoping they will do something to make this a bit more fair such as not weighting the exam towards my grade or allowing me to resit but they don't seem too keen to do much right now.

So if it comes down to it, given that the university was partly responsible for the fault that happened, would I be able to take legal action to get my university to do something to make this more fair?

Comment: The problem with this question is that "fair" and "unfair" are such vague concepts. There are of course laws that prevent unfair discrimination, such as because your race. In this case it also refers to the fact that you personally feel it's unfair for you to lose marks because of your technical issues.

Comment: The partly/partly thing is what needs to be resolved. An extreme case would be someone with sights on their smartphone stepping on a busy road being hit by a speeding car. Much would depend on how much the car was speeding to resolve responsibility. So, much depends on the details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The procedure for complaints and appeals against  the decisions of UK Universities is managed by the [Office of the Independent Adjudicator for Higher Education](https://www.oiahe.org.uk/) (known as the OIA).

They will only consider your case when you have completed any formal internal processes of the institution and the institution is required to issue you with a "completion of process" letter confirming your complaint or appeal is at an end.

To make a formal complaint or appeal within your institution you will certainly be able to get advice, help, support and representation from the Students Union and their respective Education or Welfare officer. It is highly likely that there are also University staff who can assist students with this process, perhaps called Senior Tutors, or some such title.

Before going to the formal process you should also see if an informal resolution can be made, as is often the case when it is a simple error or system fault. You might need to contact the departmental Director of Studies, Programme Director or Head of Department. You are also likely to have your own "student reps" within your class or programme that also can raise a case for you within the department. They often raise such matters of quality within a framework of a "staff student committee". The [UK Office for students](https://www.officeforstudents.org.uk/) would  likely expect such student representation to be present within a UK institution.

There will  be information about this on the web page of the university and the web pages of your students union or student association.

Comment: Oh wow that is really helpful, I think this answers my question perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are referring to a public university in the U.S., but it isn't particular clear from the question. Universities will generally have some formal or informal means by which one can "appeal" a grading decision (usually by raising an issue with a department chair or a dean), but have extremely broad discretion.

If internal universities remedies don't provide you relief, your odds of having a remedy legally enforceable in court are extremely low. Public universities also often have "sovereign immunity" from lawsuits of this kind.

Comment: I agree that the likelihood of obtaining relief is low, but I don't think sovereign immunity is the reason why. I'm sure there's some difference among the states, but I think that immunity generally only applies to claims for damages. This sounds like it would be an equitable claim.

Comment: UK tag added following clarification by the OP

Comment: sorry forgot to mention

Comment: No idea what the situation would be in the U.K., although I suspect that the distinction between governmentally owned institutions and non-governmentally owned institutions might still be material.

Comment: @ohwilleke All significant UK universities are a special class of organization called a scheduled charity, which means that legally they are separate entities from the government, but with the government being responsible for them not going insolvent.

Comment: @user1937198 Do Oxford and Cambridge have that character?

Comment: @ohwilleke Yes, they are explicitly listed in the Charities Act 2011 Schedule 3, Section 1: https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2011/25/schedule/3/enacted

Comment: @ohwilleke The reason for the government ends up ultimately responsible for their solvency is due to few odd quirks in UK charity law. So far it doesn't appear to have been tested in practise, as the universities try to keep solvent as separate corporate entities.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

But "fair" doesn't mean what you think it means.

From a legal point of view "fair" usually means that you were afforded what in the USA would be called "due process" and in most other Anglophone countries "natural justice" and/or "procedural fairness".

Whatever you call it, what it means is that your university must follow its rules and processes. If you have a right to appeal, then you have been afforded "fairness" when the university has followed the rules of that appeals process to the end.

The actual decision as to what academic grade/mark to give you is a matter within the discretion of the university. That is, it's their decision to make and so long as they followed the rules in reaching that decision, the court will not interfere.

For your particular issue, if the rules state that late submitted exams will be scored at 0; then you have been afforded "fairness" - they followed the rules that they set.

There is a lot of case law that amounts to: “We’re judges - we don’t get involved in the evaluation of academic merit or marking systems that are rightly the province of academia. All we will do is tell the institution to follow the rules it set for itself.”

Comment: Ok but what if the university had caused the submission to be late?

Comment: @AmeenIzhac what do the rules say about that?

Comment: I'm not sure, I thought that  given that students pay £9250 per year then there would be some laws to ensure they don't get unfair treatment but maybe it's specific to the university. I guess I'll see.

Comment: @AmeenIzhac Like any other business, the incentive for fair treatment is that unfair treatment leads to bad publicity.

Comment: The answerer is technically correct that universities write their own rules, and the standard of "fairness" is that the university follows the rules it's written and published.  However, in England and Wales, the Office of the Independent Adjudicator gives universities some quite strong hints as to what they might want to write in their rules.  An example of such a hint that's relevant to this case can be found [here](https://www.oiahe.org.uk/resources-and-publications/good-practice-framework/requests-for-additional-consideration/what-are-requests-for-additional-consideration/).

Comment: @DanielHatton thanks, that guide actually seems really useful, so what exactly is the Office of the Independent Adjudicator?

Comment: @AmeenIzhac See Brian Tompsett's answer.